# Does a function output parameter (a reference paramter) change before the function returns?

Tags: c++, function, return, pass-by-reference

Basically I want to know in C++ if I call a function and pass the arguments by reference, then the arguments are modified only after the function returns or it is possible that they get changed exactly when they are modified inside the body before reaching to a return point?

I need to return some objects before deleting them at the end of a function. Obviously it is not possible to access the already deleted object when the function returns.

Comment: *"before deleting them at the end of a function"* Showing code might clarify your intention...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference can be seen as an alias to the actual object it's referencing so whenever you mutate an object via a reference, it's directly affecting the referenced object.

```cpp
void foo(int& my_int) {
    my_int = 10;        // <- the change happens exactly here

    // `an_int` declared in `main` is now 10

    // do other things ...
}

int main() {
    int an_int = 0;
    foo(an_int); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When parameters are passed by reference to a function, the parameters can be modified inside the function will affect the original object passed in, and these modifications can occur at any point during the execution of the function.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument by reference you are sending a memory address so the modifications you do to the value of the variable are to the memory address.

That means that if there's another process using the same variable they'll see the change. If you remove that section of the memory it will affect anyone using it.

Comment: _"another process"_? Please clarify this since C++ doesn't deal with processes.

Comment: There is a big difference between a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) and a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_programming)).

Comment: I think I have misused the terms process here. I think it is best if we talk about scope. We could talk about threads as well, but I it's been years since I've used C++ and threads are not a simple topic.